# In proof environment , "proof" doesn't show at the beginning of a proof in pdf

Tags: amsthm

I use a proof environment in a solution environment which inside a description environment. But after compiling my tex file, in the pdf file the *proof* doesn't show at the beginning of a proof.

"solution" is a user-defined theoremstyle whose parameters are as follow:

```
\newtheoremstyle{solution}%
{}{}%
{}{-10pt}%
{\bfseries}{:}%
{\newline}%
{}
```

Except this, I don't make any changes.

Something relevant in my preamble:

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{lem}{Lemma}
```

What I did in my tex file is as follow:

```
\begin{description}
\item[1]
\begin{solution}

\begin{lem}
a lemma
\end{lem}

\begin{proof}
a proof
\end{proof}

\end{solution}
\end{description}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a compilable tex code resulting in your issue, not only a code snippet we had to guess what you are doing?

Comment: Could you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to replicate your issue?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please edit your post and add a complete but minimal example which reproduces your problem (with your documentclass, the packages you're using and the definitions you created)?

Comment: I have edited a minimal example, thanks.

Comment: That is not what they mean. We cannot copy and test your code which out having to guess parts of it. Please make this into something we can copy and test as is.

Comment: @Mico No.I have tried that, but the "proof" still disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some text after `\begin{solution}`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{solution}
  {}
  {}
  {\normalfont}
  {-10pt}
  {\bfseries}
  {:}
{0pt}%  {\newline}
  {}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{lem}{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{solution}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[1]
\begin{solution}\mbox{}

\begin{lem}
a lemma
\end{lem}

\begin{proof}
a proof
\end{proof}

\end{solution}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]